# UIPageViewController: flipping animation interrupted. (iOS7 vs iOS6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

UIPageViewController flipping animation is interrupted on high speed of swipe gesture.

What I do?

I run iOS 6 app on iOS7 device and start flip pages.
And If I too fast, pages does not animate (flip interrupted).

On iOS6 everything normal. Normal fast flipping pages.

Maybe there is a solution for my problem with UIPageViewController gestures?

Additional info:

I use dirty hack to install app on iOS7 with Xcode4.

I open Xcode5_DeveloperPreview, read DDI symbols of iOS7 device.
Next I close Xcode5_DeveloperPreview.
Next I open Xcode4 and install app on iOS7 device.

When I try to compile this app with Xcode 5 (iOS 7 sdk), nothing seems to change (flipping animation still interrupted)

Comment: Have you tried compiling the app with SDK7 and see if performance is better? Time to move on with the times.

Comment: @LeoNatan, yes, I do, but animation still interrupted. see my question update

Comment: Is this on a device or simulator? Also, are you using autolayout?

Comment: @LeoNatan: on device. no, I don't have autolayout

Comment: Does the page change or does it stay on the previous page?

Comment: Everything works, but animation not smooth enough. Animations is jumping at the end (or does not appear if user is very-very fast), but action 'flip the page' works.

Answer (score 0):

We recently had some trouble like this, the culprit was initiating some animations from a non-main thread (perhaps you are initiating a transition). This caused some trouble with animations transactions getting rolled back and this broke animations until the transaction was rolled back. There were some entries on the console pointing to CA transactions. Setting CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 on the environment quickly revealed the stack of where the the transactions were started.

The fix was to not do anything that would create transactions from a non-main thread.